# Soundcloud widget stop auto-next in playlist

Tags: soundcloud

Currently, soundcloud's embeded playlist widget automatically plays the next song in the playlist after the current one finishes. `autoplay=false` as an url option does not disable this feature. Is there an option to prevent this? Either through the url or api?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to disable this feature out-of-the-box.  There are browser addons that can do what you ask, such as [SoundCloud Continuous Play On-Off Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/soundcloud-continuous-play-/).

A hacky way to do this with JavaScript would be to find the duration of the track, and when your SoundCloud player hits that time value, jump the scrubber back to the beginning of the track, or call the Pause function.  This is outlined in this SO post: [Soundcloud HTML5 widget continuous play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129618/soundcloud-html5-widget-continuous-play).